# Errors in Android App - Cannot be resolved or isn't a feild

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am currently building an app in Eclipse from a tutorial I found, but I have 36 errors in my code. The errors that are having read that certain activities, buttons etc "cannot be resolved or is not a field"

I have included the main activity file below (MainActivity.java):

```
package com.example.youdothemath;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.R;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{
    private Button playBtn, helpBtn, highBtn;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //error

        playBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play_btn); //error
        helpBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.help_btn); //error
        highBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.high_btn); //error

        playBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        helpBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        highBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) 
    {
        //respond to clicks
        if(view.getId()==R.id.play_btn)
        {
            //play button
            private String[] levelNames = {"Easy", "Medium", "Hard"};
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Choose a level")
            .setSingleChoiceItems(levelNames, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    //start gameplay
                    startPlay(which);
                }

            });

            AlertDialog ad = builder.create();
            ad.show();
        }

        else if(view.getId()==R.id.help_btn)
        {
            //how to play button
            Intent helpIntent = new Intent(this, HowToPlay.class);
            this.startActivity(helpIntent);
        }
        else if(view.getId()==R.id.high_btn)
        {
            //high scores button
            Intent highIntent = new Intent(this, HighScores.class);
            this.startActivity(highIntent);
        }
    }

    private void startPlay(int chosenLevel)
    {
        //start gameplay
        Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, PlayGame.class);
        playIntent.putExtra("level", chosenLevel);
        this.startActivity(playIntent);
    }
 }
```

Can anyone help me? I have shown where the first 4 errors lie by commenting out the code. For example the line setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //error is coming up as an error as it says that "activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field". activity_main.xml features in my layout folder.

---

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project but its no use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't it say that **R** cannot be resolved or is not a field?

Comment: prior to creating this java file... have you created the activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

Remove

```
import android.R;
```

and save it..

Click Project from toolbar and that click clean and select your project then give ok.

```
Project - > Clean - > Select Project - > ok
```

Answer (score 0):

Its the imports, you have:

```
import android.R;
```

Instead you should have the R for your package(this or not the above line at all):

```
import com.example.youdothemath.R;
```

Try "organizing imports" - ctrl + shift + O

This can also happen if there is some other errors in your resources(the res) folder.

The compiler is looking into the Android default resources instead of the res folder for your project - your xml layout and components. That is why the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting these errors because you haven't imported the right packages.Delete `import android.R;` and press `ctrl+shift+o`, it will import the required packages.